# How can I make Webalizer work with rolling apache logs?

Tags: apache-2.2, log-files, webalizer

I am using Webalizer to view my site stats, and it's working ok with one exception; I have log rolling configured so my log directory looks something like this:

```
/var/log/apache2$ ls  
access.log  
access.log.1  
access.log.2.gz  
access.log.3.gz  
...
```

Webalizer ends up only storing the last ~4 days each time it runs, so I only ever get a rolling window of stats rather than the full month. How can I make Webalizer process the full set of logs?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

in webalizer.conf add:

```
Incremental     yes
IncrementalName webalizer.current
```

i point webalizer to already rotated file that will not change and execute it after the rotation:

```
LogFile /var/log/apache2/whatever.com-access.log.1
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll try that out. Is there a way to force it to process the last month of compressed files so I don't have to wait another month?

Comment: @Simon - i'm not sure if i get what you mean. you want to process all history? then zcat *.gz >> all and process once file called all. if processing in the middle of the month is what you mean - try running webalizer everyday on access.log - this [ i think ] should work too.

Comment: Thanks, the first suggestion should work for me - I just wanted to re-process the history that I'd lost due to not having Incremental turned on.